# azure clone bug workaround

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

Working on CD pipe line for our web applications on Azure, 
Im trying to create a deploy slot with a copy of the production site .

I tried to work with Clone in powershell with this article  :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-app-cloning

```
$srcapps = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupname -Name $webappname

$destapp = New-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupname -Name $webappname -Slot SLOTNAME -SourceWebApp $srcapps
```

But when i execute it i get error:

New-AzureRmWebAppSlot : Parameter ServerFarmId is null or empty.

Googling this error got me to this :

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3633

Saying :

> Attempting to use output object from Get-AzureRmWebApp to direct
>   Get-AzureRmWebAppSlot fails due to a typing issue, although both types
>   appear to be identical.

Describing exactly my situation

Am i missing something ?

Did any one found a work around for it ?

Any other approaches to create a deploy slot with a copy of the production site ?

thanks !

Comment: Why not add a publish step for the staging slot right after Prod?

Comment: This exactly what I did , tryed to drop a step .

Answer (score 0):

In your command, you should add `-AppServicePlan <your plan>`.

But I test in my lab, it seems it is possible for you to do this, I suggest you should clone your app firstly, then use  cloned app to create a slot.